# How to find dictionary column value contained my list value or not by using query in c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have  list of value

```
list1[110,120,130]
```

I want to check in dictionary whether my dictionary table column value like

```
110_abc_ro
120_cfg_go
130_dfg_lo
110_abc_io
170_cfg_jo
```

is contained list value or not.
I want output like
`110_abc_ro,110_abc_io` is for  list value 110

Comment: do you mean query as in `System.Linq` expressions?

Comment: yes if it is possible it will be great help

Comment: You are probably using you dictionary wrong, it seems you would probably better to use something like this. `var dict = Dictionary<int,List<string>();` or even just `List<MyObject>()` to make it easier for you to add, query and work with it... id write this in to an answer, however the question is fairly broad and `X/Y`'ish

Comment: your `list1[110,120,130]` looks more like a `Tuple` then a `Dictionary`. It could just be a point of confusion on my part.  can you provide a better snippet of your data representation.

Comment: I have database(which consist number of excel files) from there I am fetching my data in dictionary. I have a one list which contained some number like 110,120,130 . i want to figure that whether list value 110 is contained in any excel file name or not

Comment: System.Data.DataTable dt = null;                                                                     dt=connection1.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null); using this all my data will come in table

Comment: @jaymingaudana if you have no other questions please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

As I can't tell what your dictionary name/key-type is from the question, I came only as far as this. For every list-item (110, 120, etc.) you now iterate through the entries in your dictionary. Whenever a value from your dictionary contains the value you're iterating over from the list, it'll write it to a string, which you can then send/write/something else.

```
foreach (int i in list1)
{
    string output = "";

    foreach (KeyValuePair<var, string> kvp in yourDictionary)
    {
        if (kvp.Value.Contains(i.ToString()))
        {
            output += kvp.Value + ", ";
        }
    }

    //print your outputstring here.
}
```

**Edit:**

you can use `yourDictionary.Values.Select(x => x.Value.Contains(i.ToString()));` instead of the foreach. Using a little from [Lucifer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6947385/lucifer)'s answer, you can turn it into the following;

```
foreach (int i in list1)
{
    string output = String.Join(",", yourDictionary.Values.Select(x => x.Value.Contains(i.ToString())));
}
```

Comment: is it possible here that we can use query for this?

Comment: @jaymingaudana see updated answer. If you take more from Lucifer's comment you could possibly even omit the list-foreach.

Comment: You're linq will not work as per OP's requirement It will select  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<var,string>> which is not correct.

Comment: @Lucifer you are correct. I have updated the statement so it will return an `IEnumerable<string>`. This should now be fine.

Comment: Yes indeed it is compatible , you can also remove the loop over int list , see my answer to how to achieve that

Comment: @Lucifer I've choosen to not copy that too, to keep the answers different and not "just more of the same". Also; from what I can tell you're not grouping the results (i.e. first all 110, then all 120). With the example OP used, your result would be 110, 120, 130, 110. This way you have all 110's, 120's, 130's, etc. on one line. It's preference really, but it keeps the answers different :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to join all values which match your list of int

> As per MSDN this method `Concatenates` all the elements of a string collection, using the specified separator between each element.

eg:

```
  string values = String.Join(",", yourDictionary.Where(x => list.Any(ele => x.Value.Contains(ele.ToString()))).Select(x => x.Value).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string result= "";
list1.ForEach(item => {
yourDictionary.ToList().ForEach
(
    pair =>
    {
        if (pair.Value.Contains(item.ToString()))
        {
            result = result + pair.Value + ", ";
        }
    }
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have simple solution:

```
int[] list1 = { 110, 120, 130 };
List<string> dict = new List<string> { "110_abc_ro", "120_cfg_go", "130_dfg_lo", "110_abc_io", "170_cfg_jo" };

for (int i = 0; i < list1.Length; i++)
{
    string str = "Values from dictionary containing " + list1[i] + ":\n";
    str += String.Concat(dict.Where(val => val.Contains(list1[i].ToString())).Select(val => val + ", "));
    Console.Write(str);
}
```